# Remove old rows from SQL database in C# on server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

First off, I'm super new to SQL, like today brand new. Currently, I need to remove data rows that are 14 days old and older and with a percent of 0.0. If there is a change in the percent, I need to keep that row (no matter how old it is) and keep the row above and below it. I'm working on this program in Visual Studio 2013.

If this is how the data is being written to the server:

```
 public void WriteSystemOnlineHistory()
    {
        //  sql = "create table if not exists SystemOnlineHistory(Online int, Offline int,  Percent Real, dt text)";

        while (true)
        {
            int total  = GetStoreTotals("Total");
            int online = GetStoreTotals("Online");
            int offline = GetStoreTotals("Offline");
            decimal total_dec = (decimal)total ;
            decimal offline_dec = (decimal)offline;
            decimal percent = 100 * (offline_dec / total_dec);
            string dt = this.DateTimeSQLite(DateTime.Now);


            lock (systemUpdateLock)
            {



                string sql = "insert into  SystemOnlineHistory( Online, Offline, Percent,  dt) " +
                                "Values (@Online, @Offline, @Percent, @dt) ";


                using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    SQLiteCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Online", online);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Offline", offline);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent", percent);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);


                    c.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.Close();
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0));
        }
```

How do I remove old rows? It's not that I can prevent rows with 0.0 to be written either, but only remove the old rows with 0.0 and that are 14 days old (or older). I hope that makes sense. I've made a sorry attempt at this already, here it is:

```
public void RemoveSystemOnlineHistory()
    {
        lock (systemUpdateLock)
        {
            string sql = "delete from SystemOnlineHistory( Online, Offline, Percent, dt) where percent = @percent" + "Values (@Online, @Offline, @Percent, @dt) ";

            using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@percent", 0.0);

                c.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                c.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is done much better with a Stored Procedure in SQL

Comment: @GrantWinny my current method removeSystemOnlineHistory() throws errors, and I knew it wasn't going to work, I was hoping to just show my logic and thinking, even though I know it is way wrong

Comment: [SQL - DELETE Query](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-delete-query.htm)

Comment: I'm not familiar with SqlLite, but the delete statements I use (in SQL Server) don't take a "Values" clause.  Just:
Delete from SomeTable where [predicate expression]
You may find this is easier to debug using a database tool (something like SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server - no idea if such a beast exists for SQL Lite).  I also don't see your "older than 14 days" rule in the where clause.  In SQL Server, you'd want something like:
[[Delete from SystemOnlineHistory where Percent > 0 And DATEDIFF(DAY, dt, GetDate()) > 14]]